# How to Rigorously Make Two Random Choices in Succession

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $\mathcal G$ be a finite collection of rooted graphs (by a rooted graph we mean a graph which has a distinguished vertex) and $\sigma$ be a probability distribution on $\mathcal G$.

I am struggling to put down the following statement rigorously.

> Choose a graph $G$ from $\mathcal G$ randomly according to $\sigma$, and then choose an edge incident with the root of $G$ uniformly at random.

I understand what is meant by choosing a graph from $\mathcal G$ randomly.
But I am not able to formalize the choice of an edge incident with a randomly chosen graph.

---

Let me say something as to what I mean by "formalize".

Suppose we wanted to choose a graph $G$ randomly from $\mathcal G$ according to $\sigma$, and then choose a number from $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, 10\}$ uniformly at random, independently of the choice of $G$.

We can formalize this by constructing the product probability space $\mathcal G\times \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, 10\}$, where the probability measure is the product of the measure $\sigma$ and the uniform measure.

Another way would be the following: Let $X$ be a random variable valued in $\mathcal G$ whose distribution is same as $\sigma$, and $Y$ be a random variable valued in $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, 10\}$ distributed according to the uniform distribution, and assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: You are picking numbers when you should actually be picking edges ...

Comment: I was merely trying to give an example as to what I understand about choosing things randomly.

Comment: Let $\mathcal G=\{G_1,\ldots G_n\}$, with $r_i$ the root of $G_i$ and $E_i$ the set of edges incident with $r_i$. Then the probability of choosing any edge in $E_i$ is $\sigma(i)/|E_i|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shaded is already rigorous though.

Write $\cal{G}$ $=\{G_1,\ldots, G_n\}$ for some $n$ and let $v_j$ be the root of $G_j$. Then let $d_j$ be the degree of $v_j$ in $G_j$.
Let $(j,a)$ be the $a$-th edge incident to the root in graph $G_j$; $j \in \{1,\ldots, n\}$ and $a \in \{1,\ldots, d_j\}$. Then the probability of picking the edge $(j,a)$ is precisely $\sigma(j) \times d^{-1}_j$.

This above paragraph is rigorous and follows from the shaded. It is also pedantic and unnecessary; the shaded already said this, with no ambiguity.

Comment: Thank you. I guess you are right. But somehow I am uncomfortable with probability right now.